# Expectation of a stopping time with respect to some Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

> Consider a Brownian Motion $B_t$, constants $a \in \mathbb{R},b>0$ and $\tau=\inf\{t\ge 0:B_t=at+b\}$. For $\lambda \ge 0$, show that
> $$ \mathbb{E}(e^{-\lambda \tau})= \exp(-ba-b\sqrt{a^2+2\lambda})$$
> and conclude $P(\tau <\infty) = \min(1,e^{-2ba})$.

Essentially this is like taking the MGF of the random time $-\tau$ which is a function of a brownian motion.  Firstly, $$\mathbb{P}(-\tau > t) \leq \mathbb{P}(\tau \le t-1)\mathbb{P}(|B_t - B_{t-1}| \leq 2)$$
$$=\mathbb{P}(\tau \le t-1)\mathbb{P}(|at+b - a(t+1)-b(t+1)| \leq 2)$$
$$ = \mathbb{P}(\tau \le t-1)\mathbb{P}(|a+bt| \leq 2)$$ and hence shows $ \mathbb{E}(e^{-\lambda \tau})$ should be finite, but I'm not sure how to proceed as I'm getting nowhere..

I'm wondering, since It is easy to show that $e^{-\lambda \tau}$ is a martingale, if this helps.

Comment: A related question: [Distribution of hitting time of line by Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133628/distribution-of-hitting-time-of-line-by-brownian-motion)

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2107249/36150) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3031288/36150)

Comment: @saz Thanks, but why would you want to show $M_t := \exp \left(\alpha B_t-\alpha \mu t- \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 t \right)$ is a martingale? Would it be the same in this case?